# how to stop overlapping of divs?

Tags: html, css, css-float

when i set float to right for container this overlapping occurrs, what is reason for this how to avoid it?
i want yellow div to below the red one and red one should be at right ...

```css
.container {
    float: right;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<div style="display: block; margin: auto; background-color: red; height: 200px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rule `clear: both` for *red* `div`.

> This is a keyword indicating that the element is floated down to clear both left and right floats.

```css
.container {
    float: right;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<div style="display: block; margin: auto; background-color: red; height: 200px; width: 100%; clear: both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with this that I would like to point out.

1. div element is by default a block element so no need to specify `display: block;`
2. You are using `display: flex` and `float:right` on the same div you can use either of those.
3. If you want to give `float:right` you should specify `float:right` on the other div as well or use `clear: both` on the red div to get it into the normal flow.

Comment: i did not understand 2nd point , i want my div to be flex and be floated to right. for this i have to use both of them. how i to achieve that v=behavior with only flex?